# Why is my Output distorted after encoding with Expression Encoder?

Tags: avi, wmv, video-encoding, microsoft-expression

[image]

I'm a "n00b" when it comes to re-encoding files. I'm trying to re-encode an AVI into a silverlight container via [Encoding Video using Expression Encoder 4.0](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=696).

As you can see in the video, the left is the input and it looks/sounds fine. The right is the output and it... doesn't.

I'm unsure of where to go from here. I'm not sure why the output is jacked up, since the input looks fine.

```
Input Video properties: 
AVI
2.49GB
22:34
809x605
Video: TSCC 809x605 15fps [Stream 00]
Audio: PCM 22050Hz mono 352kbps [Stream 01]
```

Choice of output doesn't seem to matter, they all end up distorted like the picture shows.

Comment: I don't have Expression Encoder, but what are the specifics of that input file? Does it fail to encode any file you give it or just that particular one? Check with [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en).

Comment: It's the only one I've tried so far... let me look those up real quick.

Comment: @slhck~ Updated with info.

Comment: I guess the culprit here is that your video uses a very rare codec – the [TSCC codec](http://www.movavi.com/codec/TSCC.html). Can you check if it works with others?

Comment: @slhck What I've endedup doing is encode the video into DVD format, and am encoding THAT into Silverlight... but that seems a bit extreme since I can *PLAY* the video successfully: Including inside Expression Encoder 4. obviously this is going to be a rare problem, so what can be done to get the right decoder, since EE4 was using something different than the decoder used to play the files.